# android hierarchyviewer , do I have too many? (picture attached)

Tags: android, view, hierarchy

My app crashes with stackoverflow error on one of my activities. This is what hierarchy viewer shows, do I have too much going on?

How can I pop views out that I don't need? I've read that 15 layers is too much, do I have 15+ layers? (associated question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692620/android-mapview-activity-getting-stack-overflow-error-everytime-i-leave-it)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My app crashes with stackoverflow error on one of my activities. This is what hierarchy viewer shows, do I have too much going on?

Yes.

> How can I pop views out that I don't need? I've read that 15 layers is too much, do I have 15+ layers?

It's your job to improve the layout as we don't see it(and you didn't mention any details about it). If I remember correctly it's recommended to not have a layout deeper then 10 levels.

Comment: @CQM count boxes from left to right, you get to 16. But the 3 leftmost or so are not in your layout so you get to like 13 layers.

Comment: @CQM Nesting a layout, in layout, in another layout and so on etc. You should add the exception you get and also try to improve the layout(for example, maybe you could replace some `LinearLayouts` with `RelativeLayouts`?). Also from the top view from which the 2 top rows start, you have 5 consecutive Views/layouts. What are those?

Comment: It has to do with my tab host which has activities in them. The thing is, if I really had too many views, then every one of my tabs should cause a crash, but it only happens on a tab which loads a mapview

Comment: @Luksprog it seems to be something related to this definitely. So is there a global view thing that I can clear out or something?

Comment: @CQM I don't know what you could do. My advice would be to rethink your layout. Besides `TabActivity` being deprecated, from what I seen on stackoverflow.com there are some complaints against `TabActivity` + embeded activities in it(and `MapActivity` isn't your ordinary activity).

Comment: thank you, yes it is a combination of consolidating views and trying to limit new views (such as popup dialogs) from adding to the hierarchy. The main trick is calling `getLocalActivityManager().removeAllActivities();`